# Can One Solutions Contain Many Projects in Xcode?

Tags: xcode4.5

In vb.net it can be done. One solutions, contain many projects.

One projects can refer to the other.

It's kind of useful if you want to create slightly similar projects.

Can the same thing be done on Objective-c/xcode?

Comment: What do you mean by "solution"? Have you looked for "subprojects" in the [Xcode User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/)? There's also a thing called [Workspaces](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH7-SW1) that might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workspace in Xcode, and then place and create multiple projects in that workspace, which is similar to a solution.